# Send json document with ESP8266

Tags: c++, json, arduino, esp8266

I created a function to send a sensor value with a name to a node.js server with a http post request.

I use ArduinoJson V6 library and ESP8266HTTPClient.h

so i wrote this :

```
void stk(String name, float value)
{
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) //Check WiFi connection status
  {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    DynamicJsonDocument doc(300);
    doc["name"] = name;
    doc["value"] = value;
    serializeJson(doc, postmessage);
    HTTPClient http;                                    //Declare object of class HTTPClient
    http.begin(host);                                   //Specify request destination
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); //Specify content-type header
    int httpCode = http.POST(postmessage);              //Send the request
    String payload = http.getString();                  //Get the response payload
    doc.~BasicJsonDocument();                           //clear the DynamicJsonDocument
    if (httpCode > 199 && httpCode < 300)
    {
      Serial.println(httpCode); //Print HTTP return code
      Serial.println(payload);  //Print request response payload
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("server isn't active at the specified IP or encounter an error");
    }
    http.end(); //Close connection
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error in WiFi connection");
  }
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
}

void loop()
{
  stk("sensor1", 12);
  delay(100);
  stk("sensor2", 11.1);
}
```

and i don't know why, on my server, i only receive sensor1, and sometime an error (the SyntaxError) but it's random:

```
{ name: 'sensor1', value: 12 }
{ name: 'sensor1', value: 12 }
{ name: 'sensor1', value: 12 }
SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 29
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (G:\Calamar Industries\kraken\kraken_node\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)
    at G:\Calamar Industries\kraken\kraken_node\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (G:\Calamar Industries\kraken\kraken_node\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
    at done (G:\Calamar Industries\kraken\kraken_node\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (G:\Calamar Industries\kraken\kraken_node\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:333:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Could you help me ?
thank you.

Comment: don't call the destructor

Comment: What *are* you receiving? That might give you some insights.

Comment: @Juraj if i do this , i only have the error.

Comment: @JHBonarius i recieve only { name: 'sensor1', value: 12 }, or the error.

Comment: What is `postmessage`?

Comment: No, that's the output you see. Debug the javascript: what's `JSON.parse` actually receiving.

Comment: @Frodyne it's the serialized doc

Comment: @JHBonarius so i debugged and it receive a big message:  "{\"name\":\"sensor1\",\"value\":12}{\"name\":\"sensor2\",\"value\":11.1}{\"name\":\"sensor1\",\"value\":12}{\"name\":\"sensor2\",\"value\":11.1}{\"name\":\"sensor1\",\"value\":12}{\"name\":\"sensor2\",\"value\":11.1}{\"name\":\"sensor1\",\"value\":12}{\"name\":\"sensor2\",\"value\":11.1}{\"name\":\"sensor1\",\"value\":12}{\"name\":\"sensor2\",\"value\":11.1}{\"name\":\"sensor1\",\"value\":12}{\"name\":\"sensor2\",\"value\":11.1}{\"name\":\"sensor1\",\"value\":12}{\"name\":\"sensor2\",\"value\":11.1}... (not ended but limited by S.O.) "

Comment: I know that it is the variable that you serialize into, but what type is `postmessage`? Is it a `String` or a `std::string`? Have you read the documentation that says that `serializeJson` does not clear but only appends to those two types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You showing the message in the comments leads me to the following analysis:

Read the [ArduinoJson V6 documentation on the serializeJson() function](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/serializejson/)

> This function treats String and std::string as streams: it doesn’t replace the content, it appends to the end.

I.e. because you reuse `postmessage`, which is probably a globally declared `String` or `std::string`, you keep appending new data to it, leading to an invalid JSON string.

The solution is to declare the object locally, e.g.

```
[...]
    doc["value"] = value;
    String postmessage;
    serializeJson(doc, postmessage);
[...]
```